# How to include an additional pathname in gnome-launcher

Tags: shell, launcher, gnome-terminal

I used the following command to create a launcher

```
 gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

It created a launcher of my shell scripting file. My shell scripting file includes opening of some of the other files . These files are not opening in this launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your shell script is using files whose path is not included in the path environment variable. To do so, you have to write

```
export PATH=$PATH:<new dirctory>
```

For example, my script uses files in the directory /tmp. Then in the first line of the script, I would write:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/tmp/
```

without  '<' and '>' as the first line of your script!